# Stop Windows 8.1 automatically updating the Intel HD Graphics 4000 driver

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, intel-graphics, intel-core-i5

I have an HP Pavilion g6-2197sa laptop running Windows 8.1. The laptop originally had Windows 7, but I upgraded to 8. When I upgraded again to Windows 8.1, my Intel HD Graphics 4000 driver stopped working. The device status reported in the driver properties window showed this message:

> Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

This problem occurs for all variations of version 15.X (10.X) of the Intel HD Graphics 4000 driver that I have tried, including the [latest version](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24826/Intel-HD-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-7-8-8-1-64-bit), currently 15.33.35.64.4176 (10.18.10.4176). This problem causes numerous issues with functionality, such as preventing external monitors from working.

However, I discovered that an older version, 9.17.10.2867, does work. I thought that was the problem sorted, but after every time I install this driver, the later version 10.X is reinstalled automatically again, usually after I reboot or even sleep/unsleep.

The way I install version 9.17.10.2867 each time is by going to Device Manager > Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 > Update Driver Software > Browse my computer for driver software > Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer. Listed here are the latest version, version 9.17.10.2867, and another 10.X version.

What can I do to stop my laptop from automatically reinstalling the later version of the driver and thus keep the older, working version installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install any new (not included in Windows) driver in Windows a copy of this driver is copied inside a dedicated folder in Windows.

Your problem is that the newest version of the driver get installed from this location. That's also happen automatically every time you reboot your computer because I believe the version you try to install manifest it self as not compatible with your Windows version or does not have a validation signature and you have set the Action Center (in Control Pannel) to automatically search and resolve problems.

The best practice to avoid a particular driver from being REinstalled FROM cache is to delete its "inf" file copy from the "inf" folder under Windows directory. All the drivers you installed get a copy of their inf file named as "oemX.inf" where X is an iteration number.

To indentify which oemx.inf file is of the driver you try to remove:

Push Windows key + R to open the RUN window prompt. Type: inf. Hit Enter.
Open the log file "setupapi.dev.log" and examine the last lines looking for any mention for any oem file related to intel graphics. That's the file you need to delete from the same folder. You may also go through all the oemX.inf files and see which one belongs to the driver you wish to remove.

Now if you reinstall the old version of your driver it should stay. If not then disable the option to automatically search and resolve problems in the Action Center via Control Panel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try this out and see what happens. If this works, it might take a little while before I'm convinced, but I will come back and accept your answer if it does.

Comment: use pnputil to enum and delete drivers!

Comment: I used pnputil to do this and after a couple of reboots there has been no automatic update, so it appears that it has worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I will add that to make this work I had to turn off automatic updates in Windows Update.