# Intel HD Graphics 4000 driver error code 43 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, intel-graphics

The Intel HD Graphics 4000 driver on my HP Pavilion g6-2197sa laptop was broken, reducing its functionality, when I upgraded to Windows 10, reporting the following error:

> Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

In fact, this error first occurred when I upgraded to Windows 8.1, but I was able to fix the issue by instead installing an old driver version (9.17.10.2867) and forcing Windows [not to update](https://superuser.com/questions/909184/stop-windows-8-1-automatically-updating-the-intel-hd-graphics-4000-driver) to the later driver version.

However, I am having trouble installing the old version of the driver on Windows 10. On Windows 8.1, I installed the driver with the following command:

```
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\the\driver.cab
```

But I now get the error:

> An error occurred trying to open - C:\the\driver.cab Error: 0x80070002
>
> Error: 2
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.

The pertinent error messages in the `C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log` file are:

> Failed opening package. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_CreatePackageByPath(hr:0x80070002)
>
> Failed to get the underlying CBS package. - CDISMPackageManager::OpenPackageByPath(hr:0x80070002)
>
> Failed while processing command add-package. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80070002)

I have tried both the [32 bit](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/GRAPHICS-BOARD/INTEL/Intel-4000-HD-Graphics-Driver-917102867-for-Windows-8.shtml) and [64 bit](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/GRAPHICS-BOARD/INTEL/Intel-HD-Graphics-Driver-917102867-for-Windows-8-x64.shtml) versions of this driver (my OS installation is 64 bit), have fixed all problems found with `sfc /scannow`, have tried other versions of the graphics driver from Intel's website, and have attempted to install version driver 9.17.10.2867 via installers ([32 bit](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=ob_117239_1) and [64 bit](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=ob_117243_1)) from HP intended for Windows 8, which reported that my system did not meet the minimum requirements for installation.

I am flummoxed. Thank you!

Comment: You are not going to be able to install a Windows 8.1 driver on Windows 10, the WDDM version is entirely different, it simply won't work.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: try the latest driver: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25698/Intel-HD-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-7-8-1-10-3rd-Gen-BYT-

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried this, it produces error code 43.

Comment: @Ramhound My question is: how can I fix the graphics driver? I attempted to do this by installing the older version, which failed, and you tell me that is not possible - is there another way?

Comment: Does Windows Update find a more suitable driver?

Comment: @Moab The driver found by Windows Update also results in this problem.

Comment: All I can suggest is a clean install of w10

Comment: @Moab As the most up-to-date drivers haven't worked since Windows 8.1, I sadly have no hope that this will solve the issue. Thanks for your input, though.

Comment: install the older driver via devicemanager: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/97061-driver-install-device-manager.html and disable the automatic driver update over WU: http://superuser.com/a/947718/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981 When I use Device Manager, I get as far as selecting the driver folder and receive the message "Windows has determined that the driver software for your device is up to date." If I uninstall the current driver, I will no longer be able to select the option to update the driver and thus install the old driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I found an old version (9.17.10.2857) of the driver from HP that was intended for Windows 8 but actually worked. I installed this via HP's installer over the latest Windows 10 version (which was from Windows Update, not HP).

For anyone else trying to find this: hp.com/drivers, search your model type, change OS to Windows 8.

To stop Windows Update from replacing this driver, I downloaded Microsoft's [Windows 10 show and hide updates program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930) and hid all updates pertaining to the Intel driver I installed before Windows Update had a chance to do its thing.

I also installed a couple of other Intel drivers in the process:

- Intel Chipset Installation Utility and Driver 9.3.0.1021
- Intel Management Engine Interface (MEI) Driver 8.1.0.1263

Though I have no idea whether these made a difference but I also hid updates for these.